# Remove all records except for the last 10 per field

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to find a way to do this but I can't seem to figure out how.
The following table is the one I am trying to "clean up".

```
-------------
| Messages  |
-------------
| ID        |
| user_id   |
| msg       |
| timestamp |
-------------
```

Basically I want to remove all messages except for the latest 10 per `user_id`.
I really have no idea how to go about this.

Any suggestions would be useful.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to do this? Why?

Comment: There are over 2 million records in this table and I have no use for keeping more than 10 per user. They are never displayed nor will they ever be needed.

Answer (score 2):

See [Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) for how to write a query that finds the newest 10 rows for each `user_id`. Then you can write a query that joins with that as a subquery, and deletes rows that aren't in it.

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM YourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ...) AS t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Replace `(SELECT ...)` with a query you found in the other question.

Answer (score -1):

You need repeat this for every user.

```
DELETE FROM Messages where user_id='xyz' and ID NOT IN 
  (SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT ID FROM Messages where user_id='xyz'  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 10)
  AS TOP10)
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't allow `LIMIT` in subqueries that are used in `IN` and `NOT IN`.

Comment: having to write a separate query for each user_id is not a very good solution.

Answer (score -2):

try something like this -

```
delete from messages where ID = (SELECT ID FROM messages
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10)
```

I am not sure if this will work, but might give you an Idea of how it can be done.
I hope this helps.

Comment: If you use `=`, the subquery has to return a single ID. But your subquery returns 10 IDs.

Comment: This doesn't operate separately on each `user_id`.